# How to share folders across deploys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk for my Rails application.

My Rails application generates pdf-documents, that are stored in public/posters.

When I deploying commit in question, all files from public folder are replaced by files from deployed commit.

I other words, I'm loosing all the user-generated data after commit.

How to configure my app or AWS to make some folders shared between commits, to prevent deletion?

Thanks!

Comment: store your files on AWS S3 - if you are using paper_clip or carrier_wave you can configure those to push files to S3 or use one of the many AWS gems - https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AWS

Answer (score -1):

If you use capistrano, you can use shared_children option.

```
set :shared_children, %w(public/posters log tmp/pids)
```

Otherwise you can setup symbol link.

make shared directory for posters

add public/posters in .gitignore

make symbol link public/posters to shared/posters